# how to delete some tables from sql dump?

Tags: mysql, linux, dump

I have got dump of all sql databases.

in this dump i have got "database1", "database2", "database3"

how to take all data in another files from dump? may be some program or script?
or delete only "database2" from dump for example?

Answer (score 2):

Depends how big it is.

If it's small (i.e. < 1G) then you can easily load it into a mysql instance on a test-box (VM or somewhere) and then do another dump just containing the DBs you're interested in. This is definitely the most reliable way.

If the dump is very large, say 500G, then it could be more difficult.

Applying text-processing on mysql dump-files is not advisable because they aren't actually text files! They can contain arbitrary binary data. These binary data might happen to contain things that you're searching for (for example, if using an "awk" program to process it).

Depends on your use-case really.